# Why is this recursion function not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Here is my code:

```
#recursion function
var = 0
def recursion_function(n):
    if(n > 0):
        var + 1
        print(str(var))
        recursion_function(n-1)
recursion_function(6)
```

And here is the output:

```
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0
```

Process finished with exit code 0

How do I make the output like this:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6
```

Please help, because I can't find the recursion error...

Comment: Perhaps you meant to assign `var + 1` to something? And to top it off, `var` is global, so you'd have to do `global var`, but using a global here is a poor choice anyway. Use an accumulator argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually changing the value of var. Replace `var + 1` with `var +=1`.

```
var = 0
def recursion_function(n):
    global var
    if(n > 0):
        var += 1
        print(var)
        recursion_function(n-1)
recursion_function(6)
>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
>>>4
>>>5
>>>6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var + 1
    ^
    |
```

In your recursion_function you are not assigning var ! Also and your recursion_function does not know what this `var` is

Good way to write code

```
var = 6
def recursion_function(n):
    if(n > 0):
        print(str((var + 1)-n))
        recursion_function(n-1)
recursion_function(var)
```

Your Desired Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```